# How can i filter objects for multiple values in Python Django?

Tags: python, django, backend

I am trying to filter Objects in django for a query set instead of a single value. Please see my code below

```py
@api_view(['GET'])
def getOffersReceived(request, name):
    owner = Profile.objects.get(name=name)
    dogs = Dog.objects.filter(owner=owner)
    print(dogs)

    sittings = Sitting.objects.filter(dog=dogs)

    return Response()
```

The print(dogs) line is showing a query set of 4 values. The next step I am trying to get all the sittings that have value dog matching either one of the items in the query set.

I am getting the following error:

ValueError: The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can filter directly with:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def getOffersReceived(request, name):
    sittings = Sitting.objects.filter(dog__owner__name=name)
    # …
    return Response()
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `in` to filter the queryset:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#in

```
sittings = Sitting.objects.filter(dog__in=dogs)
```